# Funcion dentro de otra funcion JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy comenzando a estudiar JS, aun no logro comprender para que se utilizamos una funcion dentro de otra funcion. Cual es el objetivo de hacer esto?

Comment: Básicamente, todos los procesos que se ejecutan en un programa son *funciones*. Por lo tanto, no es de extrañar que dentro de una función se haga uso de otras funciones. El propósito de hacerlo así es claro: *llevar a cabo una tarea para obtener un resultado*. Saludos

Comment: Una posibilidad es "encapsular" la función para que solo pueda ser ejecutada dentro de la función donde fue declarada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es parte de la programacion enteder para que y porque vamos a utilizar cierta tecnica para resolver x o y problema, por ejemplo lo que tu comentas de llamar a una funcion a si misma se llama **recursividad**

Un ejemplo muy comun al aprender este termino es hallar el factorial de un numero.

En estos ejemplos te muestro como hallar el factorial con un bucle for simple y con una funcion recursiva.

```js
function factorial(n) {
  var total = 1;
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    total = total * i;
  }
  return total;
}




function factorialRecursivo(n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  return n * factorialRecursivo(n - 1);
}


console.log(factorial(5))
console.log(factorialRecursivo(5))
```

Si bien ambas funciones te regresaran el mismo resultado la función recursiva, se llama a si misma para darte el resultado mientras que la otra usa un for.

Son dos maneras distintias de atacar un mismo problema ,debes analizar y sacar la mejor opcion que se adopte a tus necesidades , espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

el objetivo que se suele usar es que tu tienes una función que digamos hace la validación de campos vacíos y tienes otra donde envías los datos del formulario para guardar en bd entonces para no crear una función que tenga la implementación de esas dos funciones pues haces el llamado de la función de validar y si es correcta continuas con la de enviar formulario otro caso es que puedes reutilizar funciones ya creadas y evitas crear código innecesario